# 1999 diesel Ford fiesta not starting

Tags: diesel

I'm having trouble starting a 1999 ford-fiesta, diesel (EN engine), that would be mk4 of fiesta. 
What I tried (in that order) was:

1. Changed fuel filter
2. Tried starting spray (the engine seems to have compression - it did seem to start a 
   little bit when using the spray, but stopped when no spray was given)
3. Opened the input to the injectors and turned the engine to see if it has fuel going in, 
   I did see some fuel coming out from the fuel line.

Other info:
The engine didn't overheat as far as I know, the timing belt seems intact and moving when moving the wheels when in gear.

Anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If:

- The engine does not crank / does not start, always check battery and battery connectors first
- The engine cranks but does not start, check fuse 31 and 35. Make sure the fuel pump is actually working. This can be easily done by open up your gas/fuel cap, putting your ear close and listen while having someone turn the key on (without starting the engine). You can easily hear a hissing sound / humming sound. If you can't hear anything, you might need to have your fuel pump checked.
- Also, if it's very cold, the glowplugs might also cause a problem. This is quite unlikely, but worth a check.

Answer (score 2):

If it's recently got cold, I'd suspect that the glowplugs are either dead or aren't getting power.